# Is it possible to detect key-release event in NeoVim?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

As title. I want to simulate the App-switching feature of macOS cmd+tab. To do so I need to detect the release of some key to trigger my lua function. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using (Neo)vim inside a terminal: no, not really, because the terminal just sends the keypress, and that's it. So there is no way for any application to detect anything more. As far as I know there are no terminals that implement extensions to this.

You can see exactly what the terminal sends with `<C-v>[keypress]` inside Vim and most shells. For example `<C-v>a` or `<C-v><F1>`. This sends just an `a` or `^[OP` (the code for F1, on my system anyway).

Some GUI wrappers at least have the technical capability to offer more possibilities for this, but AFAIK none do.

---

I don't know how Cmd+Tab in macOS behaves exactly; you may be able to do some cleverness to hack around things, but it probably won't be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the claraification :) And I just read a reply from reddit where they said key-holding cannot be detected too.